# SQL Query - CASE Unexpected Token

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I have the following `SQL` query:

```
SELECT w.id, w.name, m.subject, m.id 
FROM users AS w, i_c AS c,
(SELECT _id, u_id, subject FROM i_m WHERE (_id, tmstmp) IN 
        (SELECT _id, max(tmstmp) FROM i_m GROUP BY _id)) m 
        WHERE (c.uid_1 = '2' OR c.uid_2 = '2') AND 
        CASE WHEN c.uid_1 = '2' THEN w.id = c.uid_2 
        WHEN c.uid_2 = '2' THEN w.id = c.uid_1 END 
        AND (c.id = m.id) ORDER BY m.tmstmp DESC
```

It works fine on my first server but, on a second server, gives me

```
Unexpected Token. (near "c" at position 280)
```

Looked at some similar issues but still not found solution.
Seems the problem is `CASE`.

Could anyone help me? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You `CASE` is wrong,  `CASE` is an expression, not a statement, you can only specify a value in the `THEN` , not a condition.

Change it to this:

```
       w.id = CASE WHEN c.uid_1 = '2' THEN c.uid_2 
                   WHEN c.uid_2 = '2' THEN c.uid_1
              END
```

Like @Jarlh suggested, you can use `OR`s which may optimize the query slightly better:

```
WHERE ((c.uid_1 = '2' AND w.id = c.uid_2) OR
      (c.uid_2 = '2' AND w.id = c.uid_1)) AND
```

Comment: Replace the case with OR-ed conditions would be even better. (Easier to optimize.)

Comment: It "works" because MySQL makes boolean expressions actually return 0 or 1. That's something I haven't seen in any other DBMS. (I wouldn't be suprised that the second server is not actually MySQL, because the error message doesn't look like it.)